# Hibernate @Where with parameter

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For soft deletes I introduced a column `deleted`. The corresponding entries are filtered out by adding `@Where(clause = "deleted=false or deleted is null")` to the entity. However, an auditor should get the deleted entries as well. How can I add a parameter to the clause and set the property on `EntityManager` or `EntityManagerFactory`?